# remove everything but first and last 6 digits

Tags: bash, sed, scripting

I am trying to remove everything but the first number and last 6 digits from every line in a file.  So far I have removed everything but the last 6 digits using `sed` like so:

```
sed -r 's/.*(.{6})/\1/' test
```

Would there be a way for me to modify this so that I keep the first number too? This number can be any length but will always be followed by a space.  Basically, I would like to get rid of `/home/usr/file` and only keep `123456789 123456` Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Input line:

```
123455679 /home/usr/file123456
```

Desired Output:

```
123456789 123456
```

Answer (score 3):

Do the same thing you did for the end at the beginning.

```
sed -r 's/(.).*(.{6})/\1\2/' test
```

(I have no idea how efficient this is however. It might need to back-track for the length of the final match.)

To grab the first "field" (space separated) and the last six characters you can use.

```
sed -r 's/([^[:space:]]*) .*(.{6})/\1 \2/' test
```

Though I think the `awk` solution is generally a better idea.

Comment: Thank you. How would I put a space between the two numbers?

Comment: Put a space between the `\1` and the `\2` in the replacement. They are "captures" that refer to the parenthesized groups in the pattern section. You can do whatever you want with them in the replacement.

Comment: No that line is not an input @EdMorton. There could be digits in directories but the last 6 characters will always be digits. So for example, the worst it could be is : `5 /home/usr123/file123456`

Comment: Yes you are right about the first point.  But about the amount of digits to be first, I poorly worded that.  It could possibly be any length but will always have a space after it before the path.  That was poor wording on my part.

Comment: So, it could possibly be `123456789 /home/usr123/file123456` but that space will always be there.  Is there a sed statement that would work? Sorry for all the confusion.

Comment: @EtanReisner the OP neglected to tell us that the line actually will not start with digits at all but instead will start with spaces. See his comment under my answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo 5 /home/usr/file123456 | awk '{print $1,substr($2,length($2)-5,6)}'
```

Comment: No need to specify the last argument to `substr`, as it will continue to the end of the string by default.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo '123456789 /home/usr123/file123456' | sed -r 's/ .*(.{6})/ \1/'
123456789 123456
```

Comment: Thank you for all your help.  For some reason that only gives me the last 6 digits and not the number before the path (123456789). Is there any reason why this would happen?

Comment: `cat temp | sort | uniq -c | sort -rk1 | sed -r 's/ .*(.{6})/ \1/' > temp2` this is the line of code that I am using it with.

Comment: `uniq -c` puts spaces before the first digit so the actual text you want this command to process once again doesn't match what you've told us and shown in your sample input. Needless to say that is quite frustrating for those of us trying to help you. Possibly unrelated: that is a bad command line - google UUOC and the whole thing could be a single, small awk command.